# javascript: использование функции как члена класса (сокрытие функционала функции)

Tags: javascript, typescript

подскажите можно ли в javascript делать такие вещи для класса:

```
class Data {
    private: m_value: number = 0;

    set(value: number) {
        m_value = value;
    }
}
```

чтобы вместо вызова

```
myData.set(11);
```

можно было бы писать

```
myData.set = 11;
```

но при этом `set` - это именно функция (метод класса)

и соответственно в обратную сторону

Comment: [Сеттеры и геттеры](https://learn.javascript.ru/property-accessors).

Comment: @wololo, да, то что надо - совсем из головы вылетело, а такой вопрос - есть ли возможность работать с произвольными названиями - например чтобы можно было использовать такую конструкцию как `get[field] = value` вместо `get(field, value)`

Comment: «set[field] = value» (c) Можно сделать через [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set), выдав классу свойство `set = new Proxy({}, handler)`. Только не понятно, какую задачу это должно решить. Похоже на хотелку изменить синтаксис языка, а не необходимость)

Comment: Да, вроде бы можно. `let obj = {set["a a a"](val){this.t = val;}, t: 0};` `obj["a a a"] = 10;` `console.log(obj.t);`